# Replacing new tile incorrectly laid

Tags: flooring

My installer is having to go behind himself and relay the porcelain tiles in my kitchen and dining room. He used Ditra and says that he can reuse what's down there.

Some places have been torn thru the Ditra to the wood. My question is should the Ditra be replaced with new as well?

Comment: IMO, the Ditra should be replaced with backerboard. Why did the tile fail the first time?